# how to convert a png into a dataset for my predictive model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

Below is my code .

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train / 255
X_test = X_test / 25
X_train_flattened = X_train.reshape(len(X_train), 28*28)
X_test_flattened = X_test.reshape(len(X_test), 28*28)

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=(784,), activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

i can predict the dataset images. but if i try to predict a downloaded image i am getting the below error .

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2341, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2327, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2315, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2283, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 784), found shape=(None, 398, 3)
```

the below code describes how i convert my downloaded image into an array . did i do anything wrong?

```
from PIL import Image 
img = Image.open("C:/Users/hp/OneDrive/Documents/2.jpg")
img = np.array(img) # shape ----> (428, 398, 3)
model.predict(img)
```

my X_test image shape is (28,28) and size is 784 .

Comment: The error message tells you the shape of your input for layer "sequential3" is incompatible with the layer, so it seems your data has a different shape then you/your model expected. Your model is not designed to handle inputs with the shape your provide.

Comment: I tried many shapes but I am getting the same error. shall you tell me which shape I can convert ?